# Why pyspark read data from MySQL and then write to same MySQL, all value of date type column is a day ahead?

Tags: mysql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

MySQL version: 5.7.29
Spark version: spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7

1. data source in MySQL
2. spark in centos7
3. run "select now" in MySQL == run "date" in Centos7
4. Pyspark run:

a. `df.filter('date_="2017-11-25"').show()`, result is right.

```
+----------+--------+--------+
|     date_|behavior|quantity|
+----------+--------+--------+
|2017-11-25|      PV|  984879|
|2017-11-25|     fav|   31998|
|2017-11-25|     buy|   20687|
|2017-11-25|      UV|   73281|
|2017-11-25|    cart|   59972|
+----------+--------+--------+
```

b. but run the following code, all values of column `date_` are `2017-11-24` in MySQL in windows, the rest of columns contain correct data：

```
df.filter('date_="2017-11-25"').write.mode('overwrite').format("jdbc").\
    option("url", "jdbc:mysql://IP:3306/test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8&serverTimezone=UTC").\
    option("dbtable", "dailybehavior_1d_temp").\
    option("user", "root").\
    option("password", "*****").\
    option("driver", "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").\
    option("batchsize", 10000).\
    option("truncate", "true").\
    save()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I find the reason.

codes of JDBC consider the timezone of MySQL in UTC-5, but the data's timezone is UTC+8.

column date_ change type to Similar timestamps after the spark read data and hour、minute 、second are 00:00:00.

Finally, the JDBC makes date_ go backward 13 hours before writing MySQL.

I change columns date_ to string in spark before writing MySQL, the result is expected.